# Mongodb storing strings into an array is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Created this databse for chats but unable to push into chats array:-

```
const struc = new mongoose.Schema({
  NAME:String,
  CHATS:[type:string]
})

const Base = mongoose.model("bases" , struc);
const upload = new Base({NAME:"Aditya"});
upload.save();

Base.updateOne({NAME:"Aditya"} , {$push:{CHATS:"HEllo}});

app.listen(3000);
```

After Checking the Database, Its still

```
CHATS:[]
```

Comment: Is this your full code? You don't establish a connection to your Mongo database.